# Enable CiviCase component programatically

Tags: drupal, civicase, drupal-9

I am working with CiviCRM 5.59.3, and a drupal module that integrates with CiviCase. How can I check if the CiviCRM component is enabled and enable it if it is disabled? I need to do this with php.

Answer (score 3):

Calling `CRM_Core_BAO_ConfigSetting::enableComponent("CiviCase");` will enable it if not enabled already.

Comment: Hi @Binary Alchemist, the way stackexchange displays review+edit comments is bizarre. I saw your suggested edit, and accepted part of it but not the addition of the extra `if` check because the function won't do anything if it's already enabled.